# MongoDb group by combined with multiple sums and match

Tags: mongodb

I have the fields, `group_id`, `code`, `revenue`. I want to do an aggregation where the revenue is grouped by the `group_id` and summed up for each type of `code`. Also, some of the `code`s will have a combined `revenue`. So for example, for `code`s "abc" and "ghi", there will be a combined `revenue` with header "agi". How do I do this?

If the input like

```
[
  {
    "group_id": "ABC",
    "revenue": 100,
    "code": "abc"
  },
  {
    "group_id": "ABC",
    "revenue": 200,
    "code": "abc"
  },
  {
    "group_id": "ABC",
    "revenue": 200,
    "code": "def"
  },
  {
    "group_id": "ABC1",
    "revenue": 200,
    "code": "def"
  },
  {
    "group_id": "ABC",
    "revenue": 200,
    "code": "def"
  },
  {
    "group_id": "ABC1",
    "revenue": 200,
    "code": "abc"
  },
  {
    "group_id": "ABC",
    "revenue": 200,
    "code": "ghi"
  }
]
```

then the output will be

```
[
  {
    "group_id": "ABC",
    "expenses": [
      {
        "code": "agi",
        "revenue": 500
      },
      {
        "code": "def",
        "revenue": 400
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "group_id": "ABC1",
    "expenses": [
      {
        "code": "abc",
        "revenue": 200
      },
      {
        "code": "def",
        "revenue": 200
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then group by `group_id` and `code` like this:

```js
let combine = ["abc", "ghi"];

db.items.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            code: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $in: ["$code", combine] },
                    then: "agi",
                    else: "$code"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                group_id: "$group_id",
                code: "$code"
            },
            revenue: { $sum: "$revenue" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.group_id",
            expenses: {
                $push: {
                    code: "$_id.code",
                    revenue: "$revenue"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "ABC",
    "expenses" : [
        {
            "code" : "def",
            "revenue" : 400
        },
        {
            "code" : "agi",
            "revenue" : 500
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "ABC1",
    "expenses" : [
        {
            "code" : "def",
            "revenue" : 200
        },
        {
            "code" : "agi",
            "revenue" : 200
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That solves the first part. But the second part "some of the codes will have a combined revenue. So for example, for codes "abc" and "ghi", there will be a combined revenue with header "agi"." How will this be done in the query itself?

Comment: How to identify combined revenue? What is the indication that `abc` and `ghi` has to be combined?

Comment: That is decided from before by the needs of the business. So these groups are already known.

Comment: `agi` is just a renaming of the sum created by grouping `abc` and `ghi`

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks.